# AJAX, jQuery, Javascript, Form Submit & setTimout() problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, settimeout

I want to make appear a message for 3 seconds before submit when I click on my input "Add" in my form.

I really don't get it why my code doesn't work. When I click on "Add", the User is added & I'm instantly redirected to my other page. No message appears and there's no 3 sec of latency.

Can anybody help me?

```js
$('.form').submit(function() {
  $('#feedback').show();

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.form').submit();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off" class="form" method="post" action="Index.php?action=addUtilisateurs">
  <label for="pseudo">Login :</label>
  <input required="required" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" name="pseudo" type="text" id="pseudo" value="<?php if (isset($pers)) echo $pers->getLogin(); ?>">
  <label for="password">Password :</label>
  <input required="required" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php if (isset($pers)) echo $pers->getMotDePasse(); ?>" oncontextmenu="return false;">
  <input id="add" type="submit" value="Add" />
  <div id="feedback">Congratulations</div>'
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: What exactly isnt working?

Comment: Sorry, the post is now Edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you are not stopping the form submission. You need to call `preventDefault()` on the `submit` event that's raised. From there you need to raise the `submit` event on the underlying DOM element when the timer elapses. This is because if you trigger the event on the jQuery object it will be caught by your `submit` event handler and prevented again.

Also note that while it's technically possible to also achieve what you need by converting the button to `type="button"` this is not a workable solution. Firstly it breaks the functionality where the form is submit when you press return in any input field. Secondly, it breaks accessibility rules. Thirdly, it means if anyone has JS disabled in their browser then will not be able to submit your form.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$('.form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#feedback').show();

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.form')[0].submit();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```css
#feedback {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off" class="form" method="post" action="Index.php?action=addUtilisateurs">
  <label for="pseudo">Login :</label>
  <input required="required" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" name="pseudo" type="text" id="pseudo" value="<?php if (isset($pers)) echo $pers->getLogin(); ?>">
  <label for="password">Password :</label>
  <input required="required" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php if (isset($pers)) echo $pers->getMotDePasse(); ?>" oncontextmenu="return false;">
  <input id="add" type="submit" value="Add" />
  <div id="feedback">Congratulations</div>'
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: wow, thank you for all Rory ! In fact, this is correct, it works pretty fine ! :D
But I still don't get it about the "$('.form')[0]", why add a "[0]" ?

Comment: That retrieves the `Element` object, not a jQuery object. You need to raise the `submit` event on that to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: And no problem, glad to help

Comment: Alright, thank you very much for this clarification !
If the form depends on an ID & not a Class, then nothing differs ?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues here.

1. You are not stopping the form submit, so as soon as add is clicked the form will get submitted.
2. The event listener will be called recursively every time you try submit the form using submit trigger.

The code should be like below

```html
<form autocomplete="off" class="form" method="post" action="Index.php?action=addUtilisateurs">
  <label for="pseudo">Login :</label>
  <input required="required" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" name="pseudo" type="text" id="pseudo" value="<?php if (isset($pers)) echo $pers->getLogin(); ?>">

  <label for="password">Password :</label>
  <input required="required" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php if (isset($pers)) echo $pers->getMotDePasse(); ?>" oncontextmenu="return false;">
  <input id="add" type="button" value="Add" />
  <div id="feedback">Congratulations</div>'
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  $('.add').click(function() {
    $('#feedback').show();

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.form').submit();
    }, 3000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Note that change to `type="button"` is not a good idea. See my answer for the reasoning.

Comment: Ah, yes. That's also nice one.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with input type submit.
Here is your solution:

```html
<form autocomplete="off" class="form" method="post" action="Index.php?action=addUtilisateurs">
  <label for="pseudo">Login :</label>
  <input required="required" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" name="pseudo" type="text" id="pseudo" value="<?php if (isset($pers)) echo $pers->getLogin(); ?>">

  <label for="password">Password :</label>
  <input required="required" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" type="password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php if (isset($pers)) echo $pers->getMotDePasse(); ?>" oncontextmenu="return false;">

  <button id="add" type="button">Add</button>
  <div id="feedback">Congratulations</div>'
</form>
<style>
  #feedback {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  $('#add').click(function() {
    $('#feedback').show();

    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.form').submit();
    }, 3000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Note that change to `type="button"` is not a good idea. See my answer for the reasoning.